# Uniq with a block doesn't work in mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have a `Boolean` field `admin` in `User` model. But when I call **uniq** with a block, it doesn't give me correct results

```
> User.all.map &:admin
=> [true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, true]

> User.all.uniq(&:admin).count
=> 10
```

I should be getting `2` as `admin` is of type `boolean`. I tried the same thing in ActiveRecord and it works fine. Any idea?

**EDIT**

Im using mongoid 2.6.0

Ruby 1.9.3-p374

Rails 3.2.11

Comment: What does `User.all.uniq(&:admin)` print? 10 records?

Comment: @Dogbert, Yes, 10 records.

Comment: Whose `uniq` is that? `Array#uniq` or something from Mongoid? What does `User.all.to_a.uniq(&:admin)` do?

Comment: @muistooshort, I did try this before. but `User.all.to_a.uniq(&:admin)` also returns 10 records

Comment: @muistooshort, Yes the ruby im using has `Array#uniq` which takes a block. This works for me `[[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 1]].uniq &:first`

Comment: You can try: User.all.map(&:admin).uniq

Comment: @muistooshort Array#uniq works. `User.all.to_a.uniq(&:admin)` is working, but when I tried it before, it wasn'nt. Maybe my brain wasnt working :P. But the issue is still there with mongoid collection.

Comment: Cool, now things are (maybe) making sense. I'd guess that `.all.uniq` is doing the uniqueness inside MongoDB and ignoring the block whereas `.all.to_a.uniq` is using `Array#uniq` and paying attention to the block. I'm no Mongoid expert so I'm making wild guesses here. Is there any analogue to ActiveRecord's `.to_sql` for Mongoid? Is there a query log for MongoDB that you can look at? Either one would clarify which `uniq` you're using. You could also go hunting around the Mongoid source to see if it defines a `uniq` method anywhere.